# How do I setup Apple Mail to automatically move old email to the Archive folder?

Tags: ipad, icloud, mail.app, email, archive

I want Apple Mail to automatically move all email, read and unread, to the Archive folder IF it's past a certain date. I want this move to take effect on ALL my devices (mac,iPad,iPhone,etc). How can I set this up? Can I set this up from the iPad or only on the Mac?

Comment: This should be easily possible as long as the date is static. Do you, by any chance, use an IMAP email setup or some other type?

Comment: @bassplayer7 I honestly don't know. I use apple mail...I have a me.com email address. Can you describe what you mean by `IMAP email setup`?

Answer (score 2):

"I have a me.com email address." queued me in that you are probably on IMAP. Simply put IMAP syncs your mail across all your devices, instead of having to delete a particular email three different places.

So, to do what you desire, you will have to create a rule on your Mac:

1. Open Mail Settings and go to "Rules".
2. Click "Add Rule" and type in your description.
3. Create the Logic:

   - Date Received :: Is Greater Than :: [Arbitrary Number Chosen by You]
4. Under perform the following actions:

   - Move Message :: *to mailbox* :: "Archive" -> "iCloud"
5. Click "OK", then "Apply".
6. The changes should be reflected on your iPad and iPhone counter-parts after refreshing inboxes there.